# Dropbox picker has started opening in new tab rather than new window in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dropbox-api, picker

I want to open Dropbox picker in new modal window which is working fine in all browsers other than Chrome.

Can anyone help me why in Chrome it opens in new tab? How can I force it to open in new window, is there any parameter in options which I can use for that (same is the case with Google Drive picker)

Comment: The Dropbox Chooser is supposed to open in a new window, not a new tab, and there isn't an option for controlling that. It's working properly for me. What version of Chrome are you seeing this with?

Comment: I am testing it on Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) can you please share any sample with me?

Comment: I'm testing on the same version and I don't see the behavior you describe. Does the issue reproduce for you on https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser ?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue for Dropbox by updating `location=0` for `window.open()` in dropin.js:

`window.open(e, "dropbox", o + ",resizable=yes,location=0")`